# jQuery build a queue with custom functions (not talking about fx queues)

Tags: jquery, callback, queue, wait

**This is my code...**

```
var _before = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
};

var _appear = function () {
    console.log('i am in the middle of it');
};

var _after = function () {
    console.log('all done!');
};

jQuery.fn.doSomething = function() {
    this.click(function() {
        _before();
        _appear();
        _after();
    });
};

$('#someButton').doSomething();
```

**I want to build a queue inside the doSomething function to allow _before() to complete before firing _appear() and _appear() to complete before firing _after().**

**I cannot change the structure of the code.**

**Thanks**

Comment: What are _before() and _appear() really doing that would allow _appear() to start executing before _before() is done?  The way you've written it now, they're called sequentially and there are no obvious asynchronous calls involved.  Hence, _before() will finish executing before _appear() is called.

Comment: It's just an example, i would like to build a queue... right now _appear fires before _before ends...

Answer (score 2):

Can't see why it wouldn't be synchronous, as there's nothing to suggest its asynchronous.

Have you tried putting the three function calls in a function itself:

```
jQuery.fn.doSomething = function() {
    this.click(function() {
        doAll();
    });
};

jQuery.fn.doAll = function() {
    _before();
    _appear();
    _after();
};
```

Or can you not do this because you can't change the structure?